# push notifications via quickblox

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, quickblox

I am trying to implement push notifications for my app using nodejs for the backend using quickblox. I'm following the steps to do that as mentioned on the quickblox site, i.e create a session user, create a push token, and last subscribe to notification channel. I'm facing a problem with the creation of the push token. My server side code looks like this:

```
app.post('/test_quickblox', function(req, res) {

    var params = {
        login: req.user.qb_username,
        password: req.user.qb_password,
    }
    console.log(params);
    QB.createSession(params, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(result);

        var options = {};
        options.headers = {};
        options.headers['QuickBlox-REST-API-Version'] = '0.1.0';
        options.headers['QB-Token'] = result.token;
        options.body = {};
        options.body['push_token'] = {};
        options.body['push_token']['environment'] = 'development';
        options.body['push_token']['client_identification_sequence'] = '54b1e2b9e9081ed60520824054b1e2b8e9081ed60520823f';
        options.body['device'] = {};
        options.body['device']['platform'] = 'ios';
        options.body['device']['udid'] = 'e0101010d38bde8e6740011221af335301010333';

        options.url = 'http://api.quickblox.com/push_tokens.json';
        QuickbloxRequest(options, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return apiError();
            }
            console.log(response);
            res.apiSuccess();
        });
    });
});
```

when logging the response it looks like the following

> { _id: '54b1e3a1535c121c2000be66',
>     application_id: 18113,
>     created_at: '2015-01-11T02:44:49Z',
>     device_id: 0,
>     nonce: 8394,
>     token: 'bf61098a35fac9389be236caec44f0a9827630d1',
>     ts: 1420944288,
>     updated_at: '2015-01-11T02:44:49Z',
>     user_id: 2179940,
>     id: 56046 }

and the error I get is:

> {"code":null,"message":"No device registered for current user session. Device is obligatory to be able to execute actions with push token."}

I guess the problem lies in the device_id being 0.
Note that I am creating the users in another controller without supplying any device_id upon creation, so I think that might be my problem but I am new to quickblox and do not understand yet all the semantics so please help me find out what the problem is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

And here we are 4 years later and I faced the same problem. No answer, no nothing, it makes you wonder how large is the quickblox community :O

Anyway, for anyone coming here with the same problem : It seems the problem is that the Android UUID returned by PhoneGap is too short so quickblox rejects it silently.

Here is what worked for me. Pay attention to the doubling of the uuid :

```
window.device.uuid + window.device.uuid
```

JS Code :

```
            //REGISTER AS ANDROID
            var message = {
                environment: "development",
                client_identification_sequence: e.regid,
                platform: "android", 
                udid: window.device.uuid + window.device.uuid,
            }; 

            if (BBPushNotification.showLog)  console.log(message);

            QB.messages.tokens.create(message, function(err, response){
              if (err) {
                if (BBPushNotification.showLog)  console.log("Create token error : ",err);
              } else {
                if (BBPushNotification.showLog)  console.log("Create token success : ",response);
              }
            });
```

Comment: Hello, sorry to thread-jack but I am struggling to find how you obtain the client_identifcation_sequence. I have created a user session, the apns cert is on the admin panel......where do i get this mysterious CIS? Thank you